# Ionic 3- actionsheet button click event

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

Please help me to add buttonClick on actionSheet buttons in ionic 3, on click of button items i have to open modal (custom alert).Here is the code:

```
    openActionSheet() {
      console.log('opening');
     let actionsheet = this.actionSheetCtrl.create({

     title:"Assign a status to the Request",

     cssClass:'action-sheet-css',
     buttons:[{
     text: 'Collect Documents',
     icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'cog' : null,
      handler: () => {
      }
     },{
     text: 'Reschedule',
      icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'cog' : null,

     handler: function(){
       console.log("reschedule click");
     }
     },{
     text: 'Contact Error',
      icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'cog' : null,
     handler: function(){
     }
     },{
     text: 'Customer Denied',
      icon: !this.platform.is('ios') ? 'cog' : null,
     handler: function(){
     }

    }]

     });
     actionsheet.present();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add another button item to above array:

```
 buttons: [
     {
         text: 'Add',
         handler: () => {
           openModal();
         }
       }
   ]
```

Then separate method for creating a modal popup:

```
 openModal(){

 }
```

**Note:** Don't use like this `handler: function(){}` always use flat arrow functions as shown in my example above.

Comment: Thanks, it is giving error : [ts] Cannot find name 'openModal'.
any. I have created method :  openModal() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(CustomPopupPage,{},{showBackdrop:true, enableBackdropDismiss:true});
   modal.present();
 }

Comment: Can you show the final `code` which you have written? Please put that on your question.

Answer (score 1):

**Click Actionsheet button open modelcontroller page**

***home.html***

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>
      Action Sheet
    </ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <button ion-button (click)="actionSheet()">ActionSheet</button> 
</ion-content>
```

***home.ts***

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ActionSheetController, ModalController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(
    public navCtrl: NavController,
    private actionSheetController: ActionSheetController,
    private modelController: ModalController) {

  }
  actionSheet(){
    let actSheet = this.actionSheetController.create({
      title:'Open medel',
      buttons:[
        {
          text:'Archive',
          handler: ()=>{
            this.openModel();
          }
        }
      ]
    });
    actSheet.present();
  }
  openModel(){
    let model = this.modelController.create('ModelPage');
    model.present()
  }

}
```

We should give a page inside the model controller string **this.modelController.create('modelPage')**

This code work perfectly.